# Prove new group action is properly defined.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

In continuation with part (b) of the problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4506573/424260).
Show that there is injective map from the sets of actions on set $X$ to set of new-action on set $Y.$

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a pseudo-action $\star$ of $G$ on $X$.
Given $g\in G,\,x\in X$, we need to find $y\in Y$ (where $Y=\{e\star x\mid x\in X\}$ is the orbit of $e$), such that $g\star x=g\star y$.

Let $y=e\star x$.  Then $g\star y=g\star(e\star x)=ge\star x=g\star x$, as required.

Comment: Please see my last post too at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4507001/424260